# Three js No image Material : WARNING in asset size limit

Tags: npm, build

I'm working on a threeJs project and I got this 3  errors on npm run build :

1

> WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
> This can impact web performance.
> Assets:
> assets/images/67a542cb789140671d2491d8df477a72.png (4.8 MiB)
> assets/images/6376a942e1ef27fea4331307af793e1d.png (658 KiB)
> bundle.4cab645ddfe7a1d96c4e.js (3.19 MiB)

2

> WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
> Entrypoints:
> main (3.19 MiB)
> main.css
> bundle.4cab645ddfe7a1d96c4e.js

3

> WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
> You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
> For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

---

Here is the code :

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
import * as dat from 'dat.gui'
import map from './texture/earth.jpg'

import mapdump from './texture/earthbump.jpg'
import clouds from './texture/earthCloud.png'
import galaxy from './texture/galaxy.png'

// global variables
let scene;
let camera;
let renderer;
const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl");
...

// renderer setup
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
canvas: canvas,
antialias: true,
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1);
renderer.autoClear = false;
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0.0);

...

// earth 
const earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
const earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
map: new  THREE.TextureLoader().load(map),
bumpMap: new  THREE.TextureLoader().load(mapdump),
roughness: 1,
metalness: 0,
bumpScale: 0.3,
});
const earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, earthMaterial);
scene.add(earthMesh);

// cloud 
const cloudGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.02, 30, 30);
const cloudMetarial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
map: new  THREE.TextureLoader().load(clouds),
transparent: true,
});
const cloudMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeometry, cloudMetarial);
scene.add(cloudMesh);
...
```

---

[npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8NOd.png)
*how it shoud be*

---

[dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhLrq.png)
*how it is on dist*

---

[Link on  github](https://github.com/Pogatchar/LandingGlobe)
*Github*

---

Comment: These are no `three.js` related warnings. They are definitely generated by your build tool.

Comment: Are you Talking about the Webpack.commons.js ? : 
{
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use:
                [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options:
                        {
                            outputPath: 'assets/images/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using Webpack. I can just tell you that `three.js` does not report these warnings.

Comment: Anaway, I'll try to fix the build tools, thank you !